# In textFieldDidBeginEditing when I update the constrains with UIView.animate it only jumps to the final destination and doesn't animate

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5) {
        self.middleContainerCenterConstrains.constant = -70
        self.loadViewIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

There are 3 containers (top, middle,bottom). There is nothing in the bottom container. There is an UIImage in the middle container. There is a container in the top container which contains two textfields.

Only the middle container have fixed height. My goal is to move the middle container with animation when one of the textfields begin editing.

The problem is that it doesn't animate, it only jumps to the final destination.

middleContainerCenterConstrains is a vertically in container constrain (Align).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change your `textFieldDidBeginEditing` to this:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.middleContainerCenterConstrains.constant = -70
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```